# PHP- file uploading working on localhost but not in server (linux)

Tags: php, file-upload, server, localhost

Upload file not working on server but it is working on localhost. File upload permission is ON, but even getting error. I tried all the solution over internet.
Here is my code.

```
  if($submit == "UPLOAD PROFILE PICTURE") {
        $user = $_COOKIE['userId'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['userPic']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['userPic']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['userPic']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['userPic']['type'];
        $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = end($tmp);
        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

        $nameToStore = $user.".".$file_ext;
        chmod("images/users-dp/$nameToStore",0777);

        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== true){
          if($file_size < 2097152){
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/users-dp/".$nameToStore)) {
              $queryFoCheck = "SELECT * FROM profilepic WHERE user = '$user'";
              $resultFoCheck = $connection -> query($queryFoCheck);
              $countFoCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultFoCheck);
              if($countFoCheck>=1) {
                $query = "UPDATE profilepic SET piclink = '$nameToStore' WHERE user = '$user'";
                $result = $connection -> query($query);
              } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO profilepic VALUES ('$user', '$nameToStore') ";
                $result = $connection -> query($query);
              }
              header('Location: profile.php?s'); //successsfully updated
            } else {
              header('Location: profile.php?e=1'); //Cant update
            }
          } else {
            header('Location: profile.php?e=2'); //Cant update
          }
        } else {
          header('Location: profile.php?e=3'); //Cant update
        }
      }
```

Comment: I would compare your PHP / HTTPD configuration. Which "header location" does it follow? You're not really helping us without more informaiton.

Comment: If you are "getting error", what is the error? What have you tried to debug this on your own, like checking permissions, reading the server's error log,...?

Comment: i checked by calling phpinfo(). it returning header('Location: profile.php?e=1') that's mean move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/users-dp/".$nameToStore) not working

Comment: when doing echo $file_tmp; It returning temp/name.tmp on localhost but server it is temp/name , no extension

Comment: I think you have to use absolute path in second parameter of move_uploaded file function or add "/" i.e. "/images/users-dp/"

Comment: also share exact error what you are facing. I will help to to understand the problem.

Comment: Kuldeep bro /images/users-dp/ not working